# select/poll really busted with C#?

Tags: c#, api, sockets, polling

I've read lots of articles, blogs, which said that under C#, you shouldn't consider the `select/poll` because it is just not "the best way to do things" (too "Unix way")

Yes the select/pool behavior is pretty strange... But finally, why should I bother with callbacks and other delegates over a "simple" while()

Comment: Because you have `NetworkStream`, which you can use along with `await` keyword to perform async operations much more easily without blocking a thread.

Answer (score 0):

Simple does not mean optimal, performance optimization and clean code is opposite things.
If you want to write high performance server, with effective CPU utilization and memory consumption, you must bother about this.